# Can't run an old laravel project

Tags: laravel

so i've beein struggling with an old laravel project from 2018 that i can't seen to run. The probem is that the project i splittedinto two folders not a classic laravel one, there's an other one named "httpdocs" and the index.php is there, so i managed to install everything and running the migrations, but noti can't run the website ? idk why it said:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\httpdocs/../daddyshop_app/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\httpdocs\index.php on line 24
```

the autoload.php file exists

Comment: Did you run composer install ?

Comment: yes i did everything went fine

Answer (score 0):

I think this part is wired, see / and \ on the require:
`require(C:\xampp\htdocs\httpdocs/../daddyshop_app/vendor/autoload.php)`

Maybe you are setting wrongly the folder structure, or in the index.php file, you are searching in the wrong path.

For example, try checking paths are correct:

Maybe `/../../laravel-app` or `../..` or `/../laravel-app`.

You get the point, make sure paths are correct.

Comment: yes it is wired,i managed to connect the index.php from the other folder,but still can't manage to run it! it wasn't me ho created the initial project back in 2018

Comment: Any other file that require other path that colud be wrong?